# netstat filtering logic include/exclude in PowerShell

Tags: powershell, powershell-3.0

Currently, we use some logic in PowerShell to do a `netstat -ano` to get all TCP and UDP results and filter out results that we don't need to see then export it into a CSV. We want the results to only include the ***LISTENING*** and ***(blank)*** and ***non-loopback IP's***.

One example would be `netstat -ano  | Where-Object{$_ -notlike '*127.?.?.?*' -and $_ -notmatch '\[::1]' -and $_ -notmatch 'TIME_WAIT' -and $_ -notmatch 'CLOSE*' -and $_ -notmatch 'ESTABLISHED' -and $_ -notmatch 'SYN_*' -and $_ -notmatch 'FIN_*'}`.

However, we don't want to miss the other options that can come through at other times if we happen to be running our script at the same time. One I just found is **LAST_ACK** and I don't know what other options there are that our logic doesn't include already.

Is there a way to flip that logic instead of filtering out all of those matches, can we only include matches that are either ***(blank)*** or ***LISTENING*** or ***non-loopback IP's***? If not, I can add more to that logic, but just wanted to see the thoughts of some of the experts.

ANSWER:
I found all the states [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Netstat) and just updated it to include all of those.

Comment: have you taken a look at the output of `Get-NetTCPConnection` yet? [*grin*]

Comment: @Lee_Dailey Thanks for the suggestion as I've seen that's the newer alternative to netstat. I just ran it and there is no Process ID in the default results. Also, we would need to include UDP as well and that's another command it seems. I was given this script and it works but just wanted to fine-tune the filtering (if possible) to catch other wildcard situations.

Comment: i posted an Answer that shows how to make the results of `netstat` into an array of PoSh objects that you can easily filter as needed. hopefully that gives you what you need. [*grin*]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found all the states [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Netstat) and just updated it to include the LAST and now they are all there. They are as follows below:

CLOSE_WAIT, CLOSED, ESTABLISHED, FIN_WAIT_1, FIN_WAIT_2, LAST_ACK, LISTEN, SYN_RECEIVED, SYN_SEND, and TIME_WAIT.

Answer (score 0):

Don't reinvent the wheel when you don't have to. Any legitimate question has potentially already been asked and answered, multiple times, in many ways all over the web. You may not find an absolute answer in one search, and you may need to search using a different string(s), string match, exact string match, partial string match, site-specific match, etc.

Example:
['powershell filter netstat'](https://duckduckgo.com/?q=%27powershell%20filter%20netstat%27&t=h_&ia=web)

Hit(s)

> Get-NetworkStatistics - netstat -ano with filtering
>
> This code borrows from Shay Levy's Get-NetworkStatistics function.
> This function runs netstat -ano on a local or remote system and filters the results by process name, address, port, protocol or state if specified. Process names are pulled for each PID using get-process.
>
> https://gallery.technet.microsoft.com/scriptcenter/Get-NetworkStatistics-66057d71
>
> Download: https://gallery.technet.microsoft.com/scriptcenter/Get-NetworkStatistics-66057d71/file/68504/10/Get-NetworkStatistics.ps1

Use as-is or modify as needed.

Comment: Thanks for the search example, I've done so many different similar searches but will check through those results as they appear to be more specific. Also, thanks for the link to the script and I will see what I can do with that.

Answer (score 0):

here's one way to deal with what i think you want ... convert the lines of text to PoSh objects that you can filter as you want. this is old code that i wrote 3 or 4 years ago.

what it does ...

- saves the result of a `netstat` call to a $Var
- cleans out the unwanted lines
- converts each line into a CSV line
- converts the collection of CSV lines into an array of PoSh objects
- displays the collection
- displays the `.PID` property of the 0th object

the code ...

```
$Raw_Result = netstat -a -o -n

# get rid of the unwanted 1st three lines
$Raw_Result = $Raw_Result | Select-Object -Skip 3
# remove the `---` line
$Raw_Result = $Raw_Result | Select-String -Pattern '[^---]'

$Cleaned_Result = foreach ($Line in $Raw_Result)
    {
    $Line = $Line.ToString().Trim()
    if ($Line[53] -eq ' ')
        {
        $Line = $Line.Insert(53, '-NA-')
        }
    $Line = $Line -replace ' {2,}', ','

    $Line
    }


$Final_Result = $Cleaned_Result | ConvertFrom-Csv


#$Raw_Result
#$Cleaned_Result
$Final_Result
Write-Output ''
$Final_Result[0].PID
```

truncated output ...

```
Proto           : UDP
Local Address   : [::]:55356
Foreign Address : *:*
State           : -NA-
PID             : 3352

[*...snip...*] 

Proto           : UDP
Local Address   : [fe80::d129:4be7:98da:e357%14]:53382
Foreign Address : *:*
State           : -NA-
PID             : 3908


1308
```

the benefit of all that work is that you now have an easy-to-sort-or-filter collection of fairly standard objects. [*grin*]

Comment: Thanks for this code. I will see what I can do with it.

Comment: @Cory - you are welcome! glad to help a little ... [*grin*]